# WPF DataGrid with variable row heights

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am programmatically creating a DataGrid and need the row heights to be variable so that rows with multiple lines of text have a great height to accomodate the additional lines.

I tried setting the RowHeight property in code, but this requires a fixed value.  If I leave RowHeight unset it just uses an arbitrary value that does not expand if the text doesn't fit.

I would also like to have my DataGrid contents to be scaleable, so if the DataGrid is resized the actual cell resize as well, including the font inside the cells.  I could use a Viewbox for this, but I've had issues with the Viewbox as it will not grow to fit the text, it shirks/expands the text to fit in it.

Perhaps I need to walk through all of the rows and columns on a resize and set the height property manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

In your Window's constructor, do:

```
dataGrid.RowHeight = double.NaN;
```

Comment: How do I do this in code behind.  It doesn't see the DataGridView.                DataGrid myDataGrid = new DataGrid();
                // Do stuff to customize myDataGrid 
                parentGrid.Children.Add(myDataGrid);

Comment: You don't have to do it in code behind. When in design mode, click on your DataGridView, go to the properties window, search for AutoSizeRowsMode, and set it there.

Comment: The only thing I get is AutoGenerateColumns, but this is on the DataGrid.  It tells me DataGridView is not recognized.

Comment: Possibly see the issue here, I see references to DataGridView when using Windows Forms, but not WPF as I am using.

Comment: Sorry.. I misread your question. I edited to include a more relevant solution.

Comment: I read through that topic but it was dealing with the column headers and replacing spacing with line breaks.  I am using a TextBlock with word wrap, which does handle the word wrapping, but every row is the same size.  This results in my word wrapped rows cutting off the bottom of the text for the second line.  If I just make the row height larger than it is unneccesarrily large for single line text.  I could have up to 4 or 5 lines of text, so I need the grid row to resize itself as required.

Comment: It doesn't accept it, I get message that it cannot convert "Auto".

Comment: Great, that seems to work when using non scaleable text, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for using a Viewbox or other method of scaling on a DataGrid?  Ultiamtely I would like to be able to set it up that a line of text is approximately 10%, this value being configurable, of the total DataGrid height.  As the DataGrid shrinks each line of text would shrink in proportion.  So if you see 10 rows when the DataGrid is 400 pixels in height and you resized the DataGrid down to 250 pixels in height you would still see 10 rows.  I this this is not typical behaviour, but this is what has been requested of our application.

Comment: @TomStudee is there any explanation why Double.NaN sets row height to Auto ?!

Answer (score 16):

Great answer to this problem from Tom - came in very useful just now. If you want to acheive this purely in Xaml without code behind, you can add the following property in your DataGrid declaration `RowHeight="{x:Static sys:Double.NaN}"`

To get the 'sys' namespace recognised here, you would have to add`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to the xmlns declarations at the top of your Xaml file.

Comment: Thanks for providing the XAML version, @pandrew. Works quite well.